# Open the Same Page as Both Normal and Bootstrap Pop-Up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, popup, bootstrap-modal

As you can see in the picture below I have a form for adding notes and a form for editing notes on my page. What I want to do is: When I click edit button ("Düzenle" in my page), I want to open the window on the right as a pop-up.
[image]

The part codes on the left side of the picture **ProjeListPartial.cshtml:**

```
@model List<tbl_Not>
@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="portlet light bordered">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption caption-md">
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart font-dark hide"></i>
                    <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase"><a>Proje Notları Toplam: @Model.Count() </a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">
                <div class="scroller" style="height: 338px;" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="0" data-handle-color="#D7DCE2">
                    <div class="general-item-list">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="item-head">
                                    <div class="item-details">
                                        <a class="item-name primary-link">@item.Adi</a>
                                        <br />
                                        @if (Fonksiyonlar.KulYetSvys((int)Sabitler.YtkSeviyesi.TamYetki))
                                        {
                                            <span class="item-label">@item.tbl_Kullanici.Adi</span>

                                        }
                                        <span class="item-label">@item.EklenmeTarihi.ToString("dd.MM.yyy")</span>
                                        @if (Fonksiyonlar.KulYetSvys((int)Sabitler.YtkSeviyesi.BirimTamYetki) || Fonksiyonlar.KulYetSvys((int)Sabitler.YtkSeviyesi.TamYetki))
                                        { 
                                            <span class="item-status">
                                                <!-- This is my edit code -->
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("Ekle", "Not", new { ID = item.ID, ProjeID = item.ProjeID,IsProjeNotu=true })">Düzenle</a>
                                                <!--  -->
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("Sil", "Not", new { ID = item.ID, ProjeID = item.ProjeID, IsProjeNotu=true})">Sil</a>
                                            </span>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-body"> @item.Icerik </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap_number hidden-print" id="sample_3_paginate">
                <ul class="pagination" style="visibility: visible;">
                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sayfalama)
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3>Not Bulunmamaktadır.</h3>
}
```

The part codes on the right side of the picture **Ekle.cshtml:**

```
@model tbl_Not
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Not";
bool IsProjeNotu = Model.ProjeID > 0 ? true : false;
if (IsProjeNotu)
{
    Layout = null;
}
}

<div class="portlet box blue">
<div class="portlet-title">
    <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>Not Ekle/Düzenle
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="@(IsProjeNotu?"expand":"collapse")"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet-body @(IsProjeNotu?"portlet-collapsed":"")">
    <form method="post" role="form" action="@Url.Action("Ekle", "Not", new { ProjeID = Model.ProjeID, BirimID = Model.BirimID, IsProjeNotu = IsProjeNotu })">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@Model.ID" />
        <div class="form-body">
            @if (!IsProjeNotu)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-6 formbox pl">
                    <span>Birim Adı:</span>
                    <select name="BirimID" id="Birim" class="form-control">
                        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Birim)
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 pl pr formbox" onchange="return IlGetir();">
                    <span>Proje Adı:</span>
                    <select name="ProjeID" id="Projeler" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="col-md-6 pl formbox">
                <span>İl/İller:</span>
                <select multiple id="Iller" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (tbl_Il item in ViewBag.Iller)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.ID">@item.Adi</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <button id="SolaYolla" type="button" class="btn blue btn-sm" data-style="slide-up" data-spinner-color="#333">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ekle
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 formbox pr">
                <span>İl Çıkar</span>
                <select multiple id="SecilenIller" name="IlID" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (tbl_NotIlIliski item in Model.tbl_NotIlIliski.ToList())
                    {
                        <option value="@item.IlID">@item.tbl_Il.Adi</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <button id="SagaYolla" type="button" class="btn blue btn-sm" data-style="slide-up" data-spinner-color="#333">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Çıkar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 formbox  pr pl">
                <span>Başlık:</span>
                <input type="text" maxlength="250" class="form-control" style="width: 230px;" value="@Model.Adi" name="Adi" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 formbox  pr pl">
                <span>İçerik:</span>
                <textarea class="mceEditor" style="width: 230px;" name="Icerik">@Model.Icerik</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 formbox  pr pl">
            <span>Not Durumu:</span>
            @foreach (var item in Sabitler.NotDurum)
            {
                <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                    @item.Adi
                    <input @( Model.DurumID == 0 ? (item.ID == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : "") : (item.ID == Model.DurumID ? "checked='checked'" : "") ) type="radio" value="@item.ID" name="DurumID" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            }
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn blue" id="Kaydet" onclick="$('#SecilenIller option').prop('selected', true);" value="Kaydet" />
    </form>
</div>
```

When I click edit button (Düzenle), this is how a screen comes out:
[image]